# Gravity: How can i change z axis direction?

Tags: game-engine

I have upgraded from 2.66a into 2.7, now the gravity behaves weird and i can't get my model to fall smoothly on the ground plane. I think the problem is that i changed the z axis to -z or vice versa. Hoow can i fix this?

Comment: In the did you change the value for gravity to be - 9.8, in the physics sub panel in the world tab?

Comment: Yes gravity is 9.8, but model always fall off the plane, how can i "fix" the model to the plane so it has gravity but doesn't fall off gradually?

Comment: Could you post an example blend file?  Use pasteall.org

Comment: yes----->http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33665

Comment: I don't see any problem... Are you sure that file has it?

Comment: I just want that model with armature doesn't fall off the ground. Every time i rotate the plane, the mesh falls to another direction and if the plane is correct, then rotating the mesh so it is ok in relation to the plane, then it falls off towards another direction! And the model jumps by itself automatically every 2-3 seconds at least 10 meters

Comment: The file you sent only has a cube, some logic bricks, and what looks like an incomplete script, in view, at least.

Comment: http://www.pasteall.org/blend/33666